# Detailed Viewstate sizes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, firefox, viewstate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode viewstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate)

Hi again. I have an application which has a viewstate size of about 40KB which is MUCH more than it should be. I only store some simple vars in the Viewstate. I already disabled ViewState for the grids which I thought would cause that issue but they weren't the "bad" ones.

Is there any way to loop through each viewstate element and show its size? Like: 
ViewState["userId"]=2KB, ViewState["guid"]=5KB and so on?

I don't really care in which way I get this information. Coding in C# would be nice but a firefox-plugin would also be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [turn on tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx) then you should get some information about each control on the page and the size of it's viewstate.  There should be a "Control Tree" section that has a "ViewState Size Bytes" column for each control on the page.  Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 also see this [msdn post on tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972204.aspx)

Comment: Arg! I already tried that but because of my small laptop-screen I only did see until the column "type". I did not scroll to the right to see if there is more information like - well "viewstate-size" %-) thanks a lot.