# Decrypt encrypted view state string

Tags: asp.net

I want to decrypt view state of one of page from my site .View state is encrypted.
I have both validation key and encryption key.

I have view state in  encrypted string  format. How to decrypt this string in c#

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode viewstate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. This question is asking about encrypted view state but your link is about clear base64 view state

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few tools available for that like fiddler (this is a free add-on download for mozilla) or charles debugging tools.