# Determine how much data is being stored in ViewState per control

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, .net-4.0, viewstate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode viewstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate)

I've got a fairly complex page I'm working on, with lots of usercontrols, repeaters, etc.

The `ViewState` on that page has ballooned up to over 4MB, which is causing a `"Maximum Request Length Exceeded"` error on postback.  The temporary fix would be to increase the `maxRequestLength` attribute in `HttpRuntime`, but that isn't fixing the root problem.

Is anybody aware of how could I inspect/query the ViewState to see which controls are the biggest offenders?  What I'd like to try and avoid is spending a bunch of time optimizing a control that would only give me a couple kB in savings, while there are others on the page that could be stashing several hundred kB in ViewState

Thanks!

Comment: Fritz Onion's ViewStateDecoder is excellent - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) Web debugging tool
- Enable Trace for particular page: `<%@ Page Language="c#" Trace="true"%>`
- Enable Trace for whole Application in web.config so each page will show a lot of useful trace info at the bottom

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Helpful Trace indicators (in your case) are:

- Render Size bytes
- ViewState Size bytes
- ControlState Size bytes

Comment: The tracing was by far the most useful.  Thanks!