# View asp.net ViewState

Tags: .net, viewstate

How do I view the content of a .net 4.5 viewstate?

Online sites are unable to decode my own site's viewstate.

I can do whatever needed in the web.config/pages.

Comment: Right click, code source, find for `ViewState` and you will see the hell on a hidden field.

Comment: I see encrypted text, I need to decrypt it to see what's inside.

Comment: It depends if your ViewState is encrypted or not. If it's not, you can just Base64 decode it using an online tool. If it is, you'll need to create a page which has access to your application state in order to decrypt it - follow one of the suggestions listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate