# How decode IIS tracing file encoding?

Tags: c#, iis, trace

I use IIS Failed Request Tracing feature. My POST request contains binary data. This data is encoded to trace file in some unusual format. It look like URL encoding but a little bit different. Could anybody know what exactly encoding use IIS and how I can parse it back (to byte array) in C#?

Comment: Could be ViewState? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate

Comment: No, it is not ViewState. It is binary content of POST request encoded to trace file