# decoding viewstate in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, migration

As far as I know the namespace `System.Web.UI.LosFormatter`
is not available in **.net core** so the question is about the alternatives of this namespace.
More specifically I want to be able to decode ViewState parameter (similar to the Deserialize(String) method).

Is there a 3rd party library or any other way to do so?

Comment: ViewState feature is available in .net core?

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814/how-to-decode-viewstate).